# Removing only blank cells in R (not the entire row or column)

Tags: r

So I want to remove all cells that are blank within my dataset. So for example, if I had something like this, where the (..) represents blank numbers:-

```
1 10 .. 4
.. 9 10 8
14 8 12 16
```

I want to be able to remove the blank cells so that it will the produce the following outcome:-

```
1 10 10 4
14 9 12 8
   8    16
```

So even though the column length isn't the same, it basically removes all blank cells between values and pulls them all up together. I would perform this in excel, but my dataset is 6000 x 6000 long and contains a lot of blank cells for which excel has trouble dealing with, so I thought it might process faster through R.

I've already had a look at methods where you replace empty strings with NA and then perform na.omit etc, but they eliminate the entire row/column if it contains just one NA value, which is not what I want. I want to retain all the values in the column even if NAs appear, I just want the values to be grouped together if that makes sense.

Comment: Try `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) c(x[x!='..'], x[x=='..']))`

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't remove any of the empty cells, all the values still remain where they are. Thank you though for your help

Comment: My comment was based on the input data showed.  It did change as showed in the expected output.  It may be better to show your data using `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`

Comment: The values are there but it doesn't move the values up a column if say there was a blank cell above it, if that makes sense? So if in cell A3 there was a blank cell, and A4 contained a value, I would want A3 to be removed so that the value in A4 moved up one. Is that what the code you wrote out does for the input data showed on your end?

Comment: I can't show the expected result without posting it as an answer.  Anyway, i got it as what you showed as expected

Comment: `test[] <- lapply(test, function(x) c(x[x!='NA'], x[x=='NA']))`
This is what I apply as I place NA in all the blank cells, I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If you have real NAs it should be `c(x[!is.na(NA)], x[is.na(NA)])`

Comment: Ah brilliant I got it now, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data.frame is named `df` then:

```
df[df == ".."] <- NA
```

In order to get `NA`s, then:

```
func<-function(i){
  x<-as.numeric(as.character(df[,i][!is.na(df[,i])]))
  xna<-as.numeric(as.character(df[,i][is.na(df[,i])]))
  newx<-c(x,xna)
}

do.call(cbind,lapply(1:length(df[1,]),func))

> do.call(cbind,lapply(1:length(df[1,]),func))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   10   10    4
[2,]   14    9   12    8
[3,]   NA    8   NA   16
```

Comment: Ah that's great, thank you. How would I go about removing all cells with the NA values without removing the entire row however? if I do na.omit it'll remove the entire row

Comment: Basically I want all cells with NA in them removed without it removing the entire row

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'removed'. In R, NA is the indicator for an empty cell. Where you see NA, you are seeing a blank cell.

Comment: So imagine if I had a column of numbers (lets just say column A) and in cell A4 there is a blank number (labelled NA), I want to remove that cell in such a way that the value below that cell (i.e. cell A5) moves into the place of A4

Comment: That is exactly what the code I provided does. It shifts all numeric up, and all empty cells to the bottom

Comment: Oh sorry I see now! Sorry! Thank you!