# How can i ignore all empty cells in a df, without dropping entire rows / columns?

Tags: r, select, tidyverse

I have data that looks like this:

[Screenshot of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRtIU.png)

and I'm looking to ignore / drop all empty cells, ***without*** dropping entire rows or columns, in order to achieve something like this:

[Screenshot of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZcGf.png)

For each column, I want to get all of the values it contains (grouped together at the top), skipping any cells that are empty. I've tried various tidyverse solutions (select, filter), but I haven't had much luck - I have x816 columns, so I need a solution that can be applied to the entire df rather than explicitly named columns.

I know this is unusual, and all observations in a row are generally tied together (e.g. one row per participant), but in this particular instance, it doesn't matter if the row information differs across columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853702/removing-only-blank-cells-in-r-not-the-entire-row-or-column

Comment: Your data does not belong in a data.frame since it (at least the expected result) is not tabular. Thus, the result should be a list. If you have a data.frame `DF`, you can do `res <- lapply(DF, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)


df <- tibble(
  v1 = sample(c(letters[1:4], rep(NA, 20)), 20, replace = TRUE),
  v2 = sample(c(letters[1:4], rep(NA, 20)), 20, replace = TRUE),
  v3 = sample(c(letters[1:4], rep(NA, 20)), 20, replace = TRUE),
  v4 = sample(c(letters[1:4], rep(NA, 20)), 20, replace = TRUE)
)


df %>% 
  fill(names(df)) %>% 
  distinct()
```

[image]

If you don't care about the combos and only want unique values you can do this:

```
df %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  distinct(key, value) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  mutate(ord = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(key, value)

#   ord v1    v2    v3    v4   
#     1 b     b     b     c    
#     2 d     c     NA    NA   
#     3 NA    d     NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Here is a one-line solution that uses no packages.

Use na.omit on each column converting each to `ts` class.  `cbind` will then handle the varying lengths automatically.  The `[TRUE, ]` at the end removes the `ts` class.

```
# test input
DF <- data.frame(V1 = c("a1", NA, "a2"), V2 = c(NA, NA, "a3"), 
   V3 = c("a4", NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

res1 <- do.call("cbind", lapply(DF, function(x) ts(na.omit(x))))[TRUE, ]
```

giving this matrix:

```
> res1
     V1   V2   V3  
[1,] "a1" "a3" "a4"
[2,] "a2" NA   NA
```

If you prefer a data frame result use:

```
as.data.frame(res1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**2)** This is an alternate solution which is also one line and uses no packages.  It omits the NA's and then extends the resulting vector to the required number of rows.  Finally it shapes it into a data.frame.

```
res2 <- replace(DF, TRUE, lapply(DF, function(x) `length<-`(na.omit(x), nrow(DF))))
```

giving this data.frame:

```
> res2
    V1   V2   V3
1   a1   a3   a4
2   a2 <NA> <NA>
3 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

This one is slightly different since it produces a data.frame rather than a matrix and it makes the resulting data.frame the same dimensions as the input.  If you wanted to drop rows that are all NA then

```
res2[rowSums(!is.na(res)) > 0, ]
##   V1   V2   V3
## 1 a1   a3   a4
## 2 a2 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: These work perfect - the first solution is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!