# Remove/delete all blanks cells/null value from large datasets of excel file

Tags: r, excel

I want to delete all blank cells from a large dataset of excel in r studio. Then want to calculate summary (because blank cell are affecting while finding the mean of dataset of each column)

Please define the code so I can use that as I am new to r studio.

[image]

```
setwd("C:/Users/shant/Desktop/cum/AOD_xlxs")
library(xlsx)
library(readxl)
a = read_excel("Copy of upper_gange.xlsx")
myData = as.data.frame(a)
```

After converting to data frame what will be the code I should use

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "remove all blank cells". As in, you want them all to start from row 1 down?

Comment: "I am new to r studio" My question is why do you want to do it in "r studio"?

Comment: How should your result look like?  1 column of values? of 100 columns of values?   Should result be ordered, or not?    Please explain more about what you want to do (an maybe why) to understand more about this question.

Comment: yes, the result should be ordered. Further, I need a mean value from each column (blank column are affecting mean)

Comment: yes, result should be ordered.

Comment: Is this what you want? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853702/removing-only-blank-cells-in-r-not-the-entire-row-or-column>